Is a set defined by a bounded gradient compact? (with log-barrier function)
Consider an augmented function $f$ consisting of (the original cost) function $f_{0}$ with log-barrier functions $f_{i}, i \in \{1, 2\}$ such that
$$
f(x) = f_{0}(x) - \frac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^{2} \log(-f_{i}(x)),
$$
where $c > 0$ controls the quality of the log-barrier approximation.
Here, $f_{i}, i \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ are smooth convex functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
The gradient will diverge as $f_{1}(x) \to -0$ and $f_{2}(x) \to -0$.
I wonder if, for any $\delta > 0$, the set $X := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} | \lVert \nabla f(x) \rVert \leq \delta \}$ is compact.

At least, you need some properties of $f_0$ to get boundedness of $X$.

$f_0=f_1=f_2=-1$ is a counterexample

@daw A simple and good counterexample!

@gerw I could show the set $X$ is bounded (and I guess it is compact) if $f$ is strongly convex. I wonder if there is a less restrictive condition to achieve such boundedness. It seems like I need sort of regularity conditions on $f_{i}$'s. Any ideas?
